# Экспорт в Excel из MS SQL

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такой задачей. Есть MS SQl база, нужно создать акты сверки по определенным договорам, чтобы они выгружались в Excel книгу на разные листы, я воспользовался библиотекой CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.dll, но никак не могу сделать выгрузку сразу нескольких договоров на разные листы, подскажите мне альтернативу или какой-нибудь метод.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался с помощью npoi

Answer (score 4):

Инструменты для генерации документов:

1. [Open XML SDK 2.0 для Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/bb448854.aspx).
2. [Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx).
3. [excellibrary](https://code.google.com/archive/p/excellibrary/)

Генерировать автоматизированием предустановленной в `ОС` пакета `Office`, через [Office.Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx) ([пример](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm)), не советую, хотя бы потому, что хостинг это не позволит. В первую очередь, из-за соображений безопасности и стабильности. На клиентской машине использование данного способа также влечет ряд осложнений.  Можно только для *несерьезных или временных* задач. Ознакомиться с `серверной автоматизацией Office` можно тут: [Consideration for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Нужно пользоваться *автономными, не зависимыми* от предустановленной в систему `Office` средствами, примеры описал выше.

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте!

Отличный проект [npoi](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). В проекте большое количество примеров на любой вкус. 
Разные листы умеет создавать точно.

Answer (score 1):

[Работа с Com сервером Excel](http://wladm.narod.ru/C_Sharp/comexcel.html)

> В главе представлены собственные практические наработки автора по выводу информации из приложений, написанных в Visual Studio 2003/2005/2008 на C# в Excel. Все коды отлажены и неоднократно использовались.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё посмотрите в сторону [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) - это удобная обёртка над форматом OpenXML (только для файлов *.xlsx).